# Plot time without date in matplotlib or seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Hi I am working on a categorical data. I want to see device behavior on a given day. I have these as my dataframe:

On `toronto_time`, I have a `datetime64[D]`. I previously used `dt.time` to remove the date. However, it presents a datatype problem which makes it a type `object` and not `datetime64[D]`. Converting it again with `pd.to_datetime` will add a date on itself.

So I left it with the original:

```
       toronto_time             description
0      2018-09-08 00:00:50      STATS
1      2018-09-08 00:01:55      STATS
2      2018-09-08 00:02:18      DEV_OL
3      2018-09-08 00:05:24      STATS
4      2018-09-08 00:05:34      STATS
5      2018-09-08 00:06:33      CMD_ERROR
```

I tried plotting it with seaborn with these codes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
import seaborn as sns

plt.style.use('seaborn-colorblind')
plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
sns.swarmplot('toronto_time', 'description', data=df);
plt.show()
```

However the visualization is compressed on that day. I want to remove the day in the xlabel also stretch them according to hours (0:00 to 24:00)

This is what I got:
[image]

Comment: If you make a transformation of your dataframe like this `df['toronto_time'] = df['toronto_time'].dt.hour`, doesn't it provide the desired output?

Comment: It will just stay with the hour. Categories will point to specific hour.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand you... See my answer and comment on it if it doesn't produce your desired output

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you want the minutes and seconds on the graph if your ticks are only on the hour? But you can do it by setting a formatter for your axis. Although I would suggest also changing you axis limits if you're looking for ticks by the hour.

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'toronto_time': ['2018-09-08 00:00:50',
                                    '2018-09-08 01:01:55',
                                    '2018-09-08 02:02:18',
                                    '2018-09-08 03:05:24',
                                    '2018-09-08 04:05:34',
                                    '2018-09-08 05:06:33'], 
                    'description': ['STATS', 'STATS', 'DEV_OL', 'STATS', 'STATS', 'CMD_ERROR']})
df['toronto_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['toronto_time'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

plt.style.use('seaborn-colorblind')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))
sns.swarmplot('toronto_time', 'description', data=df, ax=ax)
ax.set_xlim(df['toronto_time'].min()-pd.Timedelta(1,'h'),
            df['toronto_time'].max()+pd.Timedelta(1,'h'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Here's a nice example showing how to use a locator to define how the ticks are spaced as well: http://leancrew.com/all-this/2015/01/labeling-time-series/

Comment: Nice! Thanks! Although my xticks shows (0, 3, 6, 9, 12 ... 21:00, 0:00). How can I display all hours? (0:00 to 23:59 or 0)

Comment: It's in the link at the bottom of the answer: try `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.HoursLocator())`