# Pandas time plot without date

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I've been trying hard all day long, but couldn't figure this one out. Maybe simple, but I can't get this one. There is a similar question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52291423/plot-time-without-date-in-matplotlib-or-seaborn)), but it does not resolve the issue.

Basically, I'm trying to plot data with time, but without date information. See my code below, which gives me an error.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'date_time': ['2022-01-03, 08:56:23', '2022-01-03, 09:12:39', '2022-01-04, 09:39:49', '2022-01-04, 09:45:19'],
        'value': [1200, 150, -300, 450]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

time = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time']).dt.time
value = df['value']

print(time)

plt.plot(time, value,'o--', lw=0);
plt.show()
```

I'm looking to plot value only depending on time, without date information. So, ideally, it should looks like below.

[image]

Not like this below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coerce date_time to datetime and extract the time component using strftime and the plot

```
df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['date_time']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
plt.plot(df['time'], df['value'],'o--', lw=0);
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you wanted rounded up time, see code below.

```
df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['date_time']).round('T').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')


plt.plot(df['time'], df['value'],'o--', lw=0);
plt.show()
```

Comment: You have wrong type. When you have string type values, matplot plots each as a tick . timeseries is notorious for this. Under the hood, matplotlib is set to take properly formatted datetimes. The following post discusses that to some degree https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515471/matplotlib-how-to-prevent-x-axis-labels-from-overlapping

Comment: From @Manlai answer, you can see he has created strings from the datetime and avoided consuming a datetime string. If he has to consume a date time string, it must be an actual properly formatted datetime string. If that helps

Answer (score 1):

This answer is if you're looking to simply change the tick labels. Basically, using `set_xticklabels` change the xticklabels from the default to hourly:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(df['date_time'], df['value'],'o--', lw=0)
ax.set_xticks(df['date_time'])
ax.set_xticklabels(df['date_time'].str.split(',').str[1]);
```

Output:

[image]